# Audio extraction from video issue

Tags: video, audio, conversion

I've extract audio from a mov file. The output (m4a) has the same length of the video, but it starts first.

[image: Audacity]

Starting first, audio has a silent space at the end. I tried many different audio/video converter(any video converter, avs, freemake) but the result it's always the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: What program did you use to extract the audio?

Comment: Any video converter

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they are not lining up, perhaps there is some problem with the audio track near the beginning that is causing truncation at the start.  Unless you have meaningful information there, my suggestion would be to remove the silence at the end of the audio file (since it is clear when it goes perfectly silent) and then end align rather than start align.  It appears that would likely give you proper sync.

Comment: The situation is slightly more complex because I have many mov file that I have split from a single mov file. My goal is to merge the output audio files of any mov and have a linear sound.